# Java leer Excel al arrastrarlo a un jtable

Tags: java, excel, xml, jtable, apache-poi

**Buenas**

Estoy intentando leer un archivo Excel (.xlsx) en una aplicación java para un jtable arrastrándolo directamente el archivo Excel al Jtable para llenarlo con los datos del Excel, estiy obteniendo múltiples errores los cuales creo son causados por las librerías utilizadas.

Las librerías que estoy utilizando:

- dom4j-1.6.jar
- org-apache-commons-codec.jar
- poi-4.1.0.jar
- poi-ooxml-4.1.0.jar
- poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.0.jar
- stax-api-1.0.1.jar
- xmlbeans-3.1.0

Dejo parte del código de la clase que estoy utilizando para lograr la lectura del archivo Excel:

```
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.awt.dnd.DnDConstants;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTarget;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetDragEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetDropEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class DropXlsx implements DropTargetListener {
   
    private JTable jtable;
    private DefaultTableModel tableModel;
    protected DropTarget dropTarget;

public DropXlsx() {
    }

    public void setJtable(JTable jtable) {
        this.jtable = jtable;
        dropTarget = new DropTarget(jtable, this);    
        tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
    }

    @Override
    public void dragEnter(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {/*...*/
    }

    @Override
    public void dragOver(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {/*...*/
    }

    @Override
    public void dropActionChanged(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {/*...*/
    }

    @Override
    public void dragExit(DropTargetEvent dte) {/*...*/
    }

    @Override
    public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
        try {
           
            Transferable tr = dtde.getTransferable();
            
            DataFlavor[] flavors = tr.getTransferDataFlavors();
            if (flavors.length > 0) {
                
                if (flavors[0].isFlavorJavaFileListType()) {
                    dtde.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY);
                    
                    java.util.List list = (java.util.List) tr.getTransferData(flavors[0]);
                    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                        
                        File file = new File(list.get(0).toString());
                        if (file.exists()) {
                           
                            if (file.getName().endsWith("xlsx")) {
                                readXLSX(file);
                            } else {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No es un archivo *.xlsx valido", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            }
                        } else {
                            System.err.println("error archivo no existe ");
                        }
                    }
                    dtde.dropComplete(true);
                    return;
                }
            }
            dtde.rejectDrop();
        } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException | HeadlessException ex) {
            System.err.println("Error 1" + ex.getMessage());
            dtde.rejectDrop();
        }
    }
```

Hasta este punto estoy recibiendo una nota de error en la comprobación del archivo `.xlsx` mostrada anteriormente:

```
...

if (file.getName().endsWith("xlsx")) {
                                readXLSX(file);
                            } else

...
```

continuo con la función de lectura donde también estoy consiguiendo varios errores:

```
private void readXLSX(File file) {        
        tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
        try {
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file));
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);//primeta hoja            
            Row row;
            Cell cell;

            int maxCol = 0;
            for (int a = 0; a <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); a++) {
                if(sheet.getRow(a)!=null){
                    if (sheet.getRow(a).getLastCellNum() > maxCol) {
                        maxCol = sheet.getRow(a).getLastCellNum();
                    }    
                }                
            }
            if (maxCol > 0) {
 
                for (int i = 1; i <= maxCol; i++) {
                    tableModel.addColumn("Col." + i);
                }                

                Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
                while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {

                    int index = 0;
                    row = rowIterator.next();

                    Object[] obj = new Object[row.getLastCellNum()];
                    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                        cell = cellIterator.next();

                        while (index < cell.getColumnIndex()) {
                            obj[index] = "";
                            index += 1;
                        }

                        switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                            case BOOLEAN:
                                obj[index] = cell.getBooleanCellValue();
                                break;
                            case NUMERIC:
                                obj[index] = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                                break;
                            case STRING:
                                obj[index] = cell.getStringCellValue();
                                break;
                            case BLANK:
                                obj[index] = " ";
                                break;
                            case FORMULA:
                                obj[index] = cell.getCellFormula();
                                break;                           
                            default:
                                obj[index] = "";
                                break;
                        }                        
                        index += 1;
                    }
                    tableModel.addRow(obj);
                }
                jtable.setModel(tableModel);
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nada que importar", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("Error 2" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
} //DropXlsx:end
```

En este caso estoy obteniendo la lista de errores desde el inicio del try en la lectura del archivo.

`XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file));`

Para finalizar dejo los errores generados:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap
    at clases.DropXlsx.readXLSX(DropXlsx.java:106)
    at clases.DropXlsx.drop(DropXlsx.java:79)
    at java.awt.dnd.DropTarget.drop(DropTarget.java:455)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer.processDropMessage(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:538)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer$EventDispatcher.dispatchDropEvent(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:852)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer$EventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:776)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetEvent.dispatch(SunDropTargetEvent.java:48)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4744)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processDropTargetEvent(Container.java:4599)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4461)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections4.ListValuedMap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 34 more
```

Gracias de antemano...

Comment: noclassdeffound da a entender que al ejecutar faltan dependencias que sí estaban al compilar (ListValuedMap). Revisa el classpath

Comment: Buenas, estoy obteniendo este error al ejecutarlo directamente desde netbeans, no debería esto omitir los errores de las dependencia de clases que ya están agregadas ?

Comment: Depende de cómo configures la ejecución.

Comment: como me puedo asegurar que se ejecuten las dependencias, que ya tengo en netbeans todas las librerías ?